# Is there some function in Maple which can compute the number of monomials in a polynomial?

Tags: math-software, maple

Is there some function $f$ in Maple which can compute the number of monomials in a polynomial? For example, $f(x_{1,2})=1, f(x_{1,2}+3x_{3,2}x_{2,5})=2$. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If **p** is the polynomial, use **nops([coeffs(p)])**. In other words, counting the monomials is equivalent to counting the coefficients.